# Reset a site in multisite

Tags: multisite

I am curious if this is possible, when you have a multisite you always have at least one site. This site cannot be deleted, because its the main site. How ever is there a way to reset this site, that is reset the sites database, remove all posts, plugins, themes (accept defaults for themes and plugins), remove all images and other media?

Essentially restore it to a default install?

Is there a plugin that "cleans up" the site? With other sites on the network you can delete them and problem solved but how do you clean up the main site?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic here, though answers that don't recommend plugins are possible and would be interesting ( such plugins do exist for single sites, I wouldn't know if they work with multisites )

Comment: It seems that the [plugin WordPress Reset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-reset/) can do the job. [See here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-support-59?replies=7).

Answer (score 1):

Before you select WordPress Reset to use, please check Plugin Author comments [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-reset-will-this-delete-subsites-on-a-multsite-install?replies=2).

You can only use this plugin on the sub-sites, not the parent/master site of the multisite  install.

On each sub-site you use it on, it should reset the sub-site back to the original, just installed/created status. This plugin has never really been tested on multisite, so be careful ;)

I have one solution from blog [WordPress Instant Demo Site with Multisite](http://tourkick.com/2014/wordpress-instant-demo-multisite/) Database Reset once go through it and go ahead.

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!